# Find the characetrs on the right of a specific character in a string

Tags: substring

c# Example: a is the character I want all the characters right of it like string bald I want the characters "ld" that are right of character a.

Comment: what if a is multiple times in the string ?

Comment: a cannot be multiple number of times that's the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the position of the first - with str.IndexOf('a'). So the next step is obvious:

```
var result = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('a') + 1);
```